# Code for Panoview360 to access from Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, live-streaming, 360-virtual-reality

Right now I'm doing a simple project which is building a VR (Oculus DK2) in Unity (C#) by getting the Live Feed from the **PanoView 360** Camera that I'm connecting by wireless...
i tried to use the following link to create the base structure:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z0EZ9FhQF4s ....
however since I'm a beginner at coding for device that are connected via wireless I have no have what to write in the code that i will attached to the Sphere to display the Live Feed....
I saw similar projects that uses Theta S http://lists.theta360.guide/t/theta-s-wifi-streaming-with-unity/262 ... although i have a Theta m15 this link wasn't helpful because the Theta m15 doesn't have Live Feed feature.... Refrence: SYVR360 App in App Store

Answer (score 0):

There is no official SDK for this camera but you can make one. Luckily, you have access to the official app so you can easily design the API.

**1**.Download the official app SYVR360 from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mitong.syvr360&hl=en) not App Store.

**2**.Download and install [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

**3**.Get the IP Address of the device you installed the SYVR360 app to and the IP Address of the camera. We can call this IP1 and IP2.

**4**.Open Wireshack and filter IP1 and IP2. This will make it so that you will only see captured packets from these two IP Addresses.

**5**.Connect your computer that is running Wireshack to your camera then open the SYVR360 app.

Usually, the camera will do a UDP broadcast on the network to share the stream info. I don't know for this particular camera but you can see everything it is sending on the network.

You can also see what the app is sending to the camera. Press every control button on the app then copy the message it sent to the camera. It will tell you what protocol the message is sent with such as UDP, TCP and also, the message it self.

**6**.When you are done monitoring the behavior of the camera and the app, you can use that to write your own API for the camera. You can send the-same message to the camera with the appropriate network protocol. If you still can't write one, you can create a new question with your findings and the code that doesn't work.

**NOTE**:

Some, if not most Wifi cameras requires username and password to work. When you provide the username and password, it will return the session ID that can be used to control the camera. You will find this information when you download Wireshark.

Comment: I will try to see how it work... I have a basic idea of what you are talking about.... i will let you know what i find

Comment: it seems that your method didn't work... because the device that i'm using (my phone) has to connect to the Camera by wireless and because of that i can't connect my PC to the Camera since it only allows one device to connect which because of that i can't monitor the messages between the two device ... which now i'm back to square one

Comment: In your problem, that's no such thing as "cannot". First of all, what makes you think that you cant connect multiple devices to the Camera?  What is your camera model? Please answer these two questions.

Comment: the Panoview 360 camera model is PDV3600 (I think)... i have tried to connect my PC to the camera while my phone is connected to it but it kept trying to connect to the camera for a long time until either i disconnected my phone from the camera or a message was prompted "the PC is taking too long trying to connect"... this is why i'm saying that it seems the camera only allow one device to connect

Comment: Disconnect the phone. Restart the camera then connect the computer first before connecting phone.

Comment: i tried doing that also, but my phone won't connect now and since the App is only in mobile device i can't use the Camera from my PC directly while monitoring the messages of the App.... i think the answer you wrote is logical and right however it only applies to cameras that allow more than one device to connect or when there is a PC version of the app that connects to the camera

Comment: Here, install this [Wifiinspect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.opticiancms.wifiprobe&hl=en).Open it and go to `network sniffer`. When you are done using the Camera app, close it and import the saved data from your phone to Wireshark on your computer. Another solution is to use port forwarding. Connect your phone to your computer then connect the computer to the camera. You can then intercept the message. You can Google all these for yourself. It is something hard to help if I am not in front of you but it is 100% possible to do.